# Merge_asof behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I am trying to use `merge_asof()` but it has some issues with sorting. For example:

```
trades = trades.sort_values(['user_id', 'create_at'], ascending=True)
deposits = deposits.sort_values(['user_id', 'create_at'], ascending=True)
data = pd.merge_asof(trades, deposits, on='create_at', by='user_id', direction='backward')
```

The above will throw the error:

> ValueError: left keys must be sorted

To solve it, I had to explicitly re-sort inside the `merge_asof`, i.e.

```
data = pd.merge_asof(trades.sort_values('create_at', ascending=True), 
                     deposits.sort_values('create_at', ascending=True), 
                     on='create_at', 
                     by='user_id', 
                     direction='backward')
```

Any idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueError` is legit because in the first approach, you're sorting your two DataFrames with two keys (i.e, you're sorting `by=['user_id', 'create_at']`), then trying to merge on a single one (i.e `on='create_at'`).

> `pandas.merge_asof`(*left, right, on=None,
> left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False,
> by=None, left_by=None, right_by=None, suffixes=('_x', '_y'),
> tolerance=None, allow_exact_matches=True,
> direction='backward'*)
>
> Perform a merge by key distance.
> This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys. **Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key**.
>
> Source : [[*docs*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)]